# Adding contents from an imported document to an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a novice in java having just completed the first year at college and this is my first query on stackoverflow but I have been at this for days.
I want to import name, address and salary in from a txt doc and this is working fine but I am getting the wrong read out once I add it to an arraylist and try to print that out.

Here is my import reader code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class ReadFile{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
ArrayList<Employee> peopleList = new ArrayList<Employee>();

  //Begiining of document import
  try {
  File myFile = new File("people.txt");
  FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(myFile);

  BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);


  String line = null;
  while((line = bReader.readLine()) != null){
  String[] result = line.split(";");

  String name = result[0];
  int age = Integer.parseInt(result[1]);
  double salary = Double.parseDouble(result[2]);

  peopleList.add(new Employee(name,age,salary));

  for (Employee token:peopleList)
  {

     System.out.println(peopleList);
  }
  }
  bReader.close();

  }catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Here is the contents of people.txt:

```
Jimmy;32;32000
Paul;28;28000
John;34;45234
Mike;19;19234
```

and here is the Employee class which is a subclass of Person:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Employee extends Person implements Comparable<Employee>, PartTimeAble
{

// variables for the Employee class
protected int idNumber;
// ID Number generator
protected static int nextIdNumber = 001;
private double salary = 0.00;
public double extra;

// Constructors for the Employee class
Employee(String name, int age, double salary) 
{
  // Constructors for the Employee Class 
  // call superclass form Person class
  super(name, age);
  idNumber = nextIdNumber++;
  this.salary = salary;
}

// Get Salary method
public double getSalary() 
{
   return salary;
}

// Get ID Number method
public int getIdNumber()
{
   return idNumber;
}

// Compare to method Overriding generic Compare 
public int compareTo(Employee other)
{
   //compare Result for salary
  if(salary - other.salary == 0)
  {
     return 0;
  }
  else if(salary - other.salary < 0)
  {
     return -1;
  }
  else
     return 1;
}

// Job method for Employee taken from ParTimeAble Interface
// Works out extra salary for Employee after part time salary
public void doJob(Job j)
{
   extra = (j.getPrice()-(j.getPrice()/100*60));

}

public String getDescription()
{
   return "Employee, ID:" + idNumber + "\tName: " + super.getName() + " Age: " +          super.getAge() + "\tSalary: €" + salary + "\tExtra Fee: €" + Math.round(extra);
 }
}
```

Here is the Person class:

```
public abstract class Person

{
 // variables for the Person class
 protected String employeeName = "Don't know";
 protected int employeeAge = 0;

 // Constructors for the Person class
 public Person(String name, int age)
{
   employeeName = name;
   employeeAge = age;
}

 // Get Name
 public String getName(){
  return employeeName;
}

// Get Age
public int getAge(){
  return employeeAge;
}

// Get Description
public abstract String getDescription();

}
```

and this is the output after compile:

```
Employee@e86da0
Employee@e86da0
Employee@1754ad2
Employee@e86da0
Employee@1754ad2
Employee@1833955
Employee@e86da0
Employee@1754ad2
Employee@1833955
Employee@291aff
```

Thank you in advance if anyone can help.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `System.out.println()` calls `toString()` method of the object you pass to it. So by default it prints class_name@address_in_memory. You need to override `toString()` method for your `Employee` class. Inside of `Employee` class:

```
@Override
public toString(){
return "Employee, ID:" + idNumber + "\nName: " + super.getName() + "\nAge: " + super.getAge() + "\nSalary: €" + salary + "\nExtra Fee: €" + Math.round(extra);
}
```

(I assume that this is what you want printed?)

Comment: He,Hey!! thank you very much Sir, so it's because I had the toString() as getDescription() and the code in the filereader was looking for a toString()! Anyway, that's it working now, cheers!